# Merge the same ouput into one?

Tags: php, mysql

Merge data into one?

I have this table output I'm using only inner join.

```
Name   |   Jan  |  Feb  |  Mar  | Year |
Name_1 |  0.00  |  0.00 | 10.00 | 2014 |
Name_1 |  0.00  | 10.00 | 0.00  | 2014 |
Name_2 |  10.00 |  0.00 | 10.00 | 2014 | 
Name_2 |  0.00  | 10.00 | 10.00 | 2014 | 
Name_2 |  0.00  | 10.00 | 0.00  | 2014 |
```

How can I make it into like this using php or mysql? Merging the same name into one only?

```
Name   |   Jan  |  Feb  |  Mar  | Year |
Name_1 |  0.00  | 10.00 | 10.00 | 2014 |
Name_2 |  10.00 | 10.00 | 10.00 | 2014 |
```

### This is my database

```
Table1
Name_ID=PK
Name_ID | Name |
   1    |   1  |
   2    |   2  |
Table2
Name_ID=FK to Table1.Name_ID
Name_ID=PK
Name_ID | Name_ID2  |    Date    |  PaidAmount |
   1    |     1     | 2014-01-01 |    10.00    |
   1    |     2     | 2014-02-01 |    10.00    |
   2    |     3     | 2014-01-01 |    10.00    |
   2    |     4     | 2014-02-01 |    10.00    |
   2    |     5     | 2014-03-01 |    10.00    |
```

Comment: probably doing mysql `sum()` function and then group by ?

Comment: Sum only count the number of data entries right? and if I use group by it only return 1 data column for each PK

Comment: it will be `max()` in his case

Comment: I need to get the value each Date I dunno how to do it T.T

Comment: Possibly you want GROUP BY Name, YEAR(Date) - Show us your SQL and we may be able to give better suggestions.

Comment: Sorry I forgot to include the PaidAmount
My table Jan-Dec Determined by "DATE" and so is the "PaidAmount"

Comment: Maybe you're guys confuse about it I'll try to add it in sqlfiddle